# Problems using ViewPager Example

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm an android newbie trying to use the ViewPager control which is part of the "Compatibility Package."

I first used the SDK manager to install the Extras Support Package.

I then went to https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments and got the ViewPager project and loaded it into Eclipse.

I then added a libs folder to the project and put "android-support-v4.jar" into that directory.

I did a Clean build and got all sorts of errors.  The screenshot of my project is at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39662979/viewpager.jpg.

What have I faild to do?
thanks,
Gary Blakely

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that you are using part of SherlockActionBar but the missing themes had to be referred to a miss library. In particular you have to import as a library project the Jake Wharthon's work and then link to your project as android library.

Comment: @user1058647: The [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) requirement is noted on [the home page of the repository](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus). If you get rid of the theme and get rid of the ActionBarSherlock references (e.g., inherit from `FragmentActivity` rather than `SherlockFragmentActivity`), you can avoid the ActionBarSherlock dependency, if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Theme or add the theme to your styles.xml.

I do think you don't need the Theme if you only try to use ViewPager.

So delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [ActionBarSherlock - FAQs](http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html).
There is a video that will help You get started with the library

P.S. don't forget to delete `import android.R;` if You have it